# ERROR: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<IP address>' (10061)

Tags: mysql, odbc

I am new to MySQL and my client's system admin doesn't know much about MySQL either. I've been trying to connect to a MySQL server installed in another machine using ODBC but i keep getting this error: 
ERROR: Can't connect to MySQL server on '' (10061)

Do i need to have a running MySQL too? I installed XAMPP and tried connecting but it's not working either.

Comment: Hi. In order for us to help you, you'll need to provide some examples of your code

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am not using any code though. I am just trying to connect using ODBC driver. I am going to use this on my SSIS package. I also tried using the MySQL connector for .Net on SSIS but it's not working for me either.

Comment: This error is possible to appear if the port on which MySQL is listening is not the default (3306) but another port that has been chosen alternatively. Try changing the port number to the correct one.